# Neccesitas build issue on Windows

Tags: windows-7, qt4, android-ndk, qmake

I am attempting to use Necessitas 0.3 on Windows 7 to port a cross-platform Qt application to Android (for the record: I tried this on Linux as well and just got a different set of problems).  Application consists of several shared libraries with some inter-dependencies, and a small test executable on top.

PROBLEM #1: [PROGRESS SO FAR: HAVE WORKAROUND]

Object files are generated fine but then link fails as path to object files is missing one directory separator.

I have the following in my pro file (example for one file, I have three in total):

```
CONFIG(debug, debug|release):OBJECTS_DIR += debug

SOURCES += ../../common/common.cpp
```

Object file "common.obj" gets generated and ends up in "debug" subdirectory fine, as expected.  Now I get the following error:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: debugcommon.obj: No such file or directory
```

Name of the objects directory ("debug") and object file ("common.obj") get concatenated -- directory separator between them is missing.

Relevant parts in generated Makefile:

```
OBJECTS_DIR   = debug\

OBJECTS       = debug\common.obj \

DESTDIR       =
```

QtCreator is v2.3.1 (based on 32bit version of Qt 4.8.0).

I've found a workaround for this -- don't use debug directory:

```
# CONFIG(debug, debug|release):OBJECTS_DIR += debug
```

This is not much of a problem when using shadow builds as all build junk gets separated from sources into shadow build directory anyway, but I'd still like to know why is this happening in the first place.  I've never had this issue with Qt before.  Any ideas?

PROBLEM #2: [PROGRESS SO FAR: HAVE KLUDGE]

Necessitas 0.3 alpha 4 on Windows appears to be seriously broken, to the point where it is completely useless.  I've spent several days struggling with the new problem: linker is incapable of finding NDK libraries.

I have tried two Necessitas installs -- one where I haven't modified anything, left all default values, and the second one where I tried to use newer NDK and configure everything manually.  Neither works.

Problem which I was unable to overcome was with linker.  It just can't find NDK, always fails with being unable to find "crtbegin_so.o".  There are a few answers on stackoverflow which suggest that this issue is with android-ndk-r6b which comes by default with Necessitas, but as mentioned previously I had even less luck when I tried to point Necessitas to a later NDK (I tried r8b -- the build fails very early on complaining about missing STL header files, found no solution for that).

I tried to work around this issue by just copying "crtbegin_so.o", "crtend_android.o" and "crtend_so.o" to my build directory but that doesn't get me much further -- linker fails again, this time on QtGui. This one is even more of a mystery since I'm trying to build a shared library that uses only 'core' and 'xml', not 'gui'.  I know that qmake variable QT by default contains 'core' and 'gui', but I thought this does not apply when TEMPLATE is set to 'lib'?  I removed 'gui' from both "mkspecs/android-g++/qmake.conf" and "qws.conf" (the only two places where I could find it), also carefully checked all my pro files just in case, but is still comes up with "ld.exe: cannot find -lQtGui" message.  I also tried with two versions of project's "libs.xml" -- one that had QtGui added to qt-libs, the other one without it.

I checked contents of "\Necessitas\Android\Qt\480\armeabi\lib" and everything is in there, including lots of prl and pc files full of wrong paths (leftover from developer’s machine?) -- removing those makes them disappear from generated lnk.cmdline files but that still doesn't help.  I suspect that Windows Necessitas may be unable to handle standard Windows paths containing backslash -- "missing" QtGui is located in "\Necessitas\Android\Qt\480\armeabi\lib" and lnk.cmdfile for the first module contains "-LC:\Necessitas\Android\Qt\480\armeabi\lib".  So it should be finding it, but it isn't.  All other paths in lnk.cmdline have forward slashes as directory separators.  I searched everywhere (including places like Build Environment in QtCreator) but haven't found yet where this path is coming from and how to change it.

PROBLEM #3: [PROGRESS SO FAR: HAVE KLUDGE]

I found this bit in the compile output:

```
C:/Necessitas/android-ndk-r6b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ @my_lib.so.1.0.0.lnk.cmdline
del /q 2> NUL my_lib.so.1.0.0.lnk.cmdline
ln -s my_lib.so.1.0.0 my_lib.so
ln -s my_lib.so.1.0.0 my_lib.so.1
ln -s my_lib.so.1.0.0 my_lib.so.1.0
```

"ln -s" is failing, of course, since I'm build this on Windows.  Not sure where this is coming from or how to change it to "mklink".  The only place where I found “QMAKE_SYMBOLIC_LINK = ln –s” is "\Necessitas\Android\Qt\480\armeabi\mkspecs\unsupported\win32-g++-cross\qmake.conf" but that's not it: this conf file is meant for MinGW (tried changing it anyway -- nothing).  If I add something like "QMAKE_SYMBOLIC_LINK = copy /y" then in my generated Makefile I can see that SYMLINK changes from "ln -s" to "copy /y" but this is ignored -- lnk.cmdline still gets generated with "ln -s" instead of "copy /y".

Fortunately, at least this failure is not fatal and build can continue.  I worked around this by just settings up a file copy via Qt's QMAKE_PRE_LINK:

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK += $${QMAKE_COPY} my_lib.so.1.0.0 ..\\my_lib.so $$escape_expand(\n\t)
QMAKE_POST_LINK += $${QMAKE_COPY} my_lib.so.1.0.0 ..\\my_lib.so.1 $$escape_expand(\n\t)
QMAKE_POST_LINK += $${QMAKE_COPY} my_lib.so.1.0.0 ..\\my_lib.so.1.0 $$escape_expand(\n\t)
```

PROBLEM #4: [PROGRESS SO FAR: SOLVED]

This one is actually a compile issue, for a change.  After applying workarounds for the first three problems I had a few shared libraries built, but then it started compiling one that uses quint64.  I got this error:

```
In file included from C:\Necessitas\android-ndk-r6b\platforms\android-9\arch-arm\usr\include/strings.h:42,
             from C:\Necessitas\android-ndk-r6b\platforms\android-9\arch-arm\usr\include/stdlib.h:42,
             from C:\Necessitas\android-ndk-r6b\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\include/cstdlib:68,
             from C:\Necessitas\android-ndk-r6b\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\include/bits/stl_algo.h:60,
             from C:\Necessitas\android-ndk-r6b\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\include/algorithm:62,
             from C:\Necessitas\Android\Qt\480\armeabi\include\QtCore/qglobal.h:68,
             from ..\..\..\DurianQtAndroid\jni\common\include/crossplatformstringapi.h:15,
             from ..\..\..\DurianQtAndroid\jni\common\include/common.h:18,
             from ..\..\..\DurianQtAndroid\jni\common\common.cpp:9:
C:\Necessitas\android-ndk-r6b\platforms\android-9\arch-arm\usr\include/sys/types.h:124: error: 'uint64_t' does not name a type
```

This one was an easy fix, just had to replace "android:QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x" in my pro file with "android:QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=gnu++0x" -- not a Windows problem at all!

PROBLEM #5: [PROGRESS SO FAR: NONE]

Another non-Windows problem: no support for ‘wstring’. Downloading custom crystax NDK to try (android-ndk-r7-crystax-5.beta2-windows.zip) but don't really have much hope that it will play well with Necessitas...

Comment: this is not an exercise, this is just self punishment, linux is the right ecosystem for developing for Android, if you do not want to dedicate an extra partition to a GNU/linux distribution just create a VirtualMachine.

Comment: After a couple of days of this I actually tried it on Linux.  Huge disappointment -- big mess as well.  To start with, most file permissions are just a random mess, no rhyme or reason to them -- you have to run QtCreator as root.  Tried it for a day and came back to Windows -- Linux is no improvement, it's just trading one set of problems for another one.